# how to create countdown timer using JavaScript in asp.net core?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I'm tying to create a countdown timer for online test using JavaScript in asp.net core.
I want it to change every 1 second without refreshing the page.
when I run the program it doesn't show me the countdown.

This my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    countdown = function () {
    var current = parseInt(document.getElementById("timerLabel").innerHTML);
    document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = current;
    if (current > 0) {
        setTimeout('countdown()', 1000); // run every second
    }}
```

This is my view:
I used foreach loop to show this.

```
 <div class="panel-footer">
            <p>   @item.Grade</p>
            <p>  @item.StartTime</p>
            <p id="EndTime">  @item.EndTime</p>
            <span id="timerLabel">@ViewBag.LeftTime</span>
            <p id="left"></p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not get the timerLabel value inside the function unless you also set it
2. Use interval and clear it when done

```js
let current = parseInt(document.getElementById("timerLabel").innerHTML);
const countdown = function() {
  document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = --current || "Done"; // using current when 0 it is false
  if (current <= 0) clearTimeout(tId); // stop the interval
};
const tId = setInterval(countdown, 1000)
```

```html
<span id="timerLabel">10</span>
<p id="left"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you.It works. but how can I use my own left time dynamically from database?

Comment: My code will work with your `@ViewBag.LeftTime` My `10` is just an example

Comment: Assuming @ViewBag.LeftTime is in seconds - if not let me know

Comment: my code does't work with viewbag but it works with 10.

Comment: The please tell me what view source shows in that p

Comment: You of course need to get your server to put something sensible in there